# Pointers - Strings

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a code chunk which is quite meaningless for me. Is there someone can explain it to me?

Thanks

```
int strLength(char *str) {
char *p = str;
// Go until the end of the string
while (*p != ‘\0’)
p++;
return (p – str);
}
```

Firstly I dont get the idea behind return section of the code.

Secondly

```
char *p = str;
```

it didn't fit me perfectly

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you understand the `while` loop? Do you understand the idea of subtracting one pointer from another? How about setting one pointer equal to another?

Comment: `str` is you. `p` is your friend. You start standing in the same place then your friend takes a step for each letter in a string. You measure the distance between your friend and you to tell how many steps they took..

Answer (score 0):

The string is stored in memory sequentially, The idea is to find the character that ends the string (in C the accepted symbol is '\0'), you increment the pointer p until you find this symbol.

When you find '\0' , You substract between two addresses to find the length.